# How to get nameContextElementPreUnbound() method (sessionEventTrigger class) triggered when the weblogic session expires in ATG?

Tags: weblogic-10.x, atg

I created a class A that extends SessionEventTrigger. I even implemented methods nameContextElementPreBound and nameContextElementPreUnbound. PreBound method gets triggered when my session starts but preUnbound is never triggered even if the session expires.
I tried setting the session-timeout in web.xml which made my application expire but the unbound method does not gets triggered.

I am using weblogic10.3 as the server and ATG10.2 for development.

One more problem is, this unbound method gets triggered exactly after 1 hour which is the default expire time for weblogic. So, I am not able to customize the expire session time. We need this to be triggered so as to save the data just before the session expires.
Please provide help in this topic as i couldn't find the solution anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `/atg/dynamo/servlet/sessiontracking/GenericSessionManager.singleSessionIdPerUser` to true.

Comment: Thanks a lot @radimpe..It actualy worked for me. Now I am able to get the get unbound method triggered.

Comment: Please suggest how can we get the profile from NameContextBindingEvent as we need to save the profile before the session expires. I tried using NameResolver but it fetches null profile component. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @zenith I think you'll need to raise this as a new question because you'll have a lot more luck getting people to contribute. Generally they don't read new questions in comments.